# Find the Laplace transform of the following functions : $i)\ \sin(t-2π) H(t-2π) \\ ii) \ \sin3t\ \delta(t-π)$

Tags: laplace-transform

> Find the Laplace transform of the following functions :
> $$i)\ \sin(t-2π) H(t-2π) \\
>   ii) \ \sin3t\ \delta(t-π)$$

I could do the first one as follows :
$H(t-2π) = u_{2π}(t)$ where $u$ is the unit step funtion.

Let, $f(t) = \sin t$. Then Laplace transform of $f(t)$ is $F(s) = \frac{1}{s^2+1}$.

Then, $$\sin(t-2π) H(t-2π) \\
       = f(t-2π) \ u_{2π}(t) \\
= u_{2π}(t)f(t-2π)
$$

Now we know Laplace transform of $$u_c(t)f(t-c)$$ is $$e^{-cs}F(s)$$.

Hence the required Laplace transform is
$$ e^{-2πs} \frac{1}{s^2+1}$$.

But I haven't found any formula for the second one. Can anyone please help me with that and alsp check if I've done the first one correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first formula is correct. Lets use the definition for the second one

$$ \int_0^\infty \sin (3t) \delta(t - \pi) e^{-st} \ dt = \sin(3\pi)e^{-s\pi} = 0, $$
by using the properties of the [delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)

Comment: So whenever dirac delta appears with trigonometric functions I should go for the definition. Right?

Comment: That would be my approach. Though I would extend that to any (non-pathological?) function, not just trig.

Comment: Okay thank you.

Comment: what property did you use of dirac function here? I've gone through your link but I'm not understanding it. The translation property has integral over whole $\mathbb{R}$. But gere the limits of the integral are $0$ and $\infty$.

Comment: The sifting property. It is closely related to the translation section. The integral does not need to go over all of $\mathbb R$. It just needs to be an interval which contains the "sifted" point.